# how to put an eclipse project into github

Tags: eclipse, git

I have an empty repo in git hub.
I have a project full of code in Eclipse.
I have the EGit plugin installed in eclipse.

If I right click on the project, and say share, then select git, it only gives the option to create a local repo - no ability to select a remote one to check the code into or to clone.

This seems like a massive omission in the plugin.

Not sure what to do now.  I could install an external git command line, and do it all from there, but kind of defeats the object of the git plugin.  I guess I need to clone the emtpy repo in an emtpy dirctory using the git command line, then copy all my project over using file explorer, then add, commit and push all the files to the repo.  Then i guess I need to create a new project in eclipse, and try and get it to check the project out from scratch from git, then delete the old project.  Not sure which files I have to avoid copying though.  Surely there is an easier way?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you have to do:

1. Clone your remote repo using action in "Git Repositories" View
2. "Share" your project into the local repo you just created by cloning
3. Commit your code to local repo using "commit" action on the repo in "Git Repositories" View or Team -> Commit on the project.
4. Push all changes to remote repo using "Push to Upstream" action on the repo in "Git Repositories" View or Team -> "Push to Upstream" on the project.

In general you need to read up on eGit: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide

Answer (score 0):

The idea of git is that it is distributed version control system - i.e. there is no one central location for saving the code, but every local machine has repository. Github is just like a social network for coders to share and look at public code.

To do what you say, create a remote repo in github and add it like this `git remoteadd origin https://github.com/yourname/yourrepo"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control